# Оптимизировать алгоритм поиска кратных чисел

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация

Надо найти все числа кратные хотя бы одному из 2-х чисел(напр. 7 и 19) и вернуть список кратных чисел. Требование вывести именно **список** кратных чисел, поэтому тут никак не схитрить. Я решил оптимизировать код и не использовать простой перебор всех чисел. Первая мысля - это взять наименьшее число и прибавлять каждый проход это же число(напр. кратность 7 т.е. 7 а дальше 14, 21 и т д. и аналогично для второго числа). Для эксперимента я замерил время моего "эффективного" алгоритма и время простого перебора - выхлоп не очень, на отрезке от 0 до 100 млн выигрыш 1-3 секунд(на отрезках много меньше выигрыш вообще в пределах погрешности). Из этого два вопроса: 1) есть ли более эффективный алгоритм для поиска 2(а может и более) кратных чисел? 2) влияет конкретно в python тот факт, что я +- 10 млн чисел запихал в память влияет на производительность?

предложенный алгоритм

```
def sol (count, num1, num2):
res = []
working = True
flag1 = True
flag2 = True

while(working):
    if num1 <= count:
        res.append(num1)
        num1 += 3
    else:
        flag1 = False
        
    if num2 <= count:
        res.append(num2)
        num2 += 5
    else:
        flag2 = False
        
    if not(flag1 or flag2):
        working = False
    
    
res = list(set(res))
return res
```

как я сделал простой перебор

```
def sec_sol(count, num1, num2):
res = []
for i in range(count + 1):
    if i % num1 == 0 or i % num2 == 0:
        res.append(i)
        
res = list(set(res))
return res
```

и вот замеры по времени с модулем time()

11.5572 -  первый "эффективный" алгоритм
12.6264 -  простой перебор

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то такое будет работать быстрее:

```
def multiples(nums, upper_limit):
    s = set()
    for n in nums:
        s.update(range(n, upper_limit, n))
    return sorted(s)


print(len(multiples((7, 19), 100_000_000)))
```

> ```
> $ time python multiples.py
> 18796992
>
> real  0m2.268s
> user  0m1.776s
> sys   0m0.484s
> ```

**P.S.** В вопросе, кажется, мало смысла. Расскажите зачем вам это нужно.

Comment: В школе учили писать код, чтоб меньше действий делал и , желательно, как быстро, как только может + желание сэкономить хотя бы время выполнения, если на системных ресурсах не сэкономить. Ну и попытка писать эффективный код

Comment: Мой код работает быстро не потому что это хороший алгоритм. Это медленный и расточительный алгоритм. Но Питон так устроен, что этот код оказывается достаточно быстрым. Трудно объяснить на пальцах.

Answer (score 4):

А не хотите найти НОК и дальше не мучиться?...

```
def gcd(m,n):
    while m != 0 and n != 0:
        if m < n:
            n %= m
        else:
            m %= n
    return m+n

def lcm(m,n):
    return (m//gcd(m,n))*n

def sol (count, num1, num2):
    res = []
    l = lcm(num1,num2)
    for i in range(1,count+1):
        res.append(l*i)
    return res
```

Да, ваше

> числа кратные заданным 2м числам

я рассматриваю как кратные одновременно обоим заданным числам. Если это не так, перепишите условие как *кратные хотя бы одному из двух заданных чисел*.

**Update**

Тогда примерно так:

```
def sol (num1, num2, count):
    res = []
    if num1 > num2:
        tmp = num1
        num1 = num2
        num2 = tmp

    k = 0
    m1 = num1
    m2 = num2
    while 1:
        if m1 < m2:
            res.append(m1)
            m1 += num1
        elif m1 > m2:
            res.append(m2)
            m2 += num2
        else:
            res.append(m2)
            m2 += num2
            m1 += num1
        if m1 > count or m2 > count:
            break
    return res
```

Comment: Список в ответе не нужен. `range` представляет нужное множество.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Подправьте, как надо. python я знаю на уровне очень слабого чайника...

Comment: `range(l, count + 1, l)` - это всё что нужно чтобы выразить арифметическую прогрессию.

Comment: @Harry, правильно заметили, кратные хотя бы одному из 2-х. Исправил уже

Comment: Тогда см. дополненный ответ...

Comment: `count` у ТС не количество элементов списка, а ограничение на числа в списке сверху.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy OK, все равно мне за вами не угнаться - при вашем знании инструмента :) Кстати, в тех "чайниковых" руководствах, что мне попадались, нигде не видел нормального, как в С++, описания — вот эта структура/алгоритм работают с O(N), а эти с O(N^2), грубо говоря... Так что я не очень понимаю к тому же, что для какой задачи можно применять.

Comment: Алгоритмически ваш алгоритм самый быстрый. Но вы делаете 18 миллионов циклов на Питоне, а я делаю их на C (операции с множествами и сортировка). И хотя ваш алгоритм линейный, а мой NlogN, на современных компьютерах не хватит памяти, чтобы logN стал достаточно велик и "перебил" разницу в константах. Потому я и говорю что задача странная. Выигрывает не тот кто пишет лучший алгоритм, а тот кто ловчее подбирает операции. Этакая учебная антизадача.

Comment: @Harry А вот например https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity